# How to convert .mat Matlab file to nii.gz Nifti file?

Tags: python, matlab, mat-file, nifti

I have a .mat file, the size of which is 512x512x251. How can I convert .mat Matlab file to nii.gz Nifti file?
Given that I'm not available for Matlab program, I want to do it with python.

What I want to do is

```
10000130.mat -> 10000130.nii.gz
```